# create a link in windows so it can find msbuild without full path

Tags: powershell, msbuild

Not sure how to do this... I work mostly on OSX and linux systems, so when I install an app or use for example G++ or xcodebuild, I just call it from terminal.

On Windows, I did install msbuild with VS2015, but if I am in powershell or regular command prompt, typing `msbuild` result in an error. I have to specify the whole path to make it work.

What is the equivalent in Windows world, of setting console so when I type msbuild, it gets the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create just a link to msbuild you still won't be able to call for example the compiler from the command line. Which is why VS provides a convenient (pretty much canonical) way to do this by supplying a batch file which sets up the PATH and all the other build-related environment variables.

Example if you are on cmd.exe:

```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"

> msbuild
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
...
> cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24213.1 for x86
...
```

You can invoke this from the Start menu as well: hit start, type `pro vs` to look for matches, select `Developer Command Prompt for VS2015`.

For PowerShell (which I'd recommend spending time on instead of cmd) you'll need an extra function like presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21652729/128384

Comment: Thanks  a lot! Do I have to call the VSDevCmd every time? The machine usually stay up but I may need to reboot it at times.

Comment: You need to call it everytime you launch a process in which you need it, i.e. it doesn't set global system-wide environment variables for the OS (that would be a disaster with regards to building with different versions of VS). So every time you start PS or cmd and need the build tools, call it once. Nice thing about PS: add a function to your profile and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your path like so in:

#### PowerShell

```
$Env:Path = "<Path_to_msbuild>;${Env:Path}"
```

#### Batch/Cmd

```
set "PATH=<Path_to_msbuild>;%PATH%"
```

***Note:** The `<path_to_msbuild>` is the folder where `msbuild.exe` exists, and NOT the direct path to the executable itself*

#### How it works

This will add the `msbuild` binary to your path, so you can invoke it from anywhere!

To verify which location `msbuild` is running from you can simply run (*in both languages!*):

```
where.exe msbuild
```

Comment: `where.exe msbuild` won't help here, otherwise there wouldn't be any need to add the MSBuild directory to the path, would there?

Comment: `Where.exe` here is used as a ***verification*** step to check that msbuild was added correctly to the `PATH` variable

Comment: Fair enough. You can actually discover the path with `where.exe`, though, if you know at least the rough location: `where.exe /r "C:\Program Files" msbuild`

Comment: weird I can't call msbuild using full path in PowerShell

Comment: I have a feeling you've added `msbuild.exe` in your path. That's not how PATHs work. https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html You need to add the `<folder_path_to_msbuild>`. I made my answer more explicit!