# How do I use/install ICU and make use of it in my C++ Visual Studio 2022 project?

Tags: c++, c++17, cygwin, visual-studio-2022, icu

I am quite new to C++ and have been trying to use the ICU library for the past few days. I have followed [this guide](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4c/build.html#how-to-build-and-install-on-windows-with-cygwin) on the ICU GitHub, to little avail.

I found that I can `#include <icu.h>` natively, but I am not sure what functionality that provides, and how to use it, and the file looks stripped. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/international-components-for-unicode--icu-) discusses how it is used on Windows, but it is not particularly specific.

I tried installing it following the [instructions on GitHub with Cygwin](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4c/build.html#how-to-build-and-install-on-windows-with-cygwin). The installation for VS2022 seems to require Cygwin . I was unsuccessful, getting this output.

```
PS C:\Users\user\Dev\ICU\icu\source> bash ./runConfigureICU Cygwin/MSVC
export CPP= CC=cl CXX=cl CPPFLAGS= CFLAGS=-Gy -MD  CXXFLAGS=-Gy -MD  LDFLAGS= MAKE=
Running ./configure   for Windows with Cygwin using Microsoft Visual C++ compiler

checking for ICU version numbers... release 73.1, library 73.1, unicode version 15.0
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking whether to build debug libraries... no
checking whether to build release libraries... yes
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Dev/ICU/icu/source':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
./runConfigureICU: ./configure failed
```

config.log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by ICU configure 73.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = desktop
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.4.6-1.x86_64
uname -s = CYGWIN_NT-10.0-22621
uname -v = 2023-02-14 13:23 UTC

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Eclipse Adoptium/jre-17.0.7.7-hotspot/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/windows/system32
PATH: /cygdrive/c/windows
PATH: /cygdrive/c/windows/System32/Wbem
PATH: /cygdrive/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
PATH: /cygdrive/c/windows/System32/OpenSSH
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/dotnet
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/CMake/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Users/user/.dotnet/tools


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2706: checking for ICU version numbers
configure:2739: result: release 73.1, library 73.1, unicode version 15.0
configure:2778: checking build system type
configure:2792: result: x86_64-unknown-cygwin
configure:2812: checking host system type
configure:2825: result: x86_64-unknown-cygwin
configure:2883: checking whether to build debug libraries
configure:2895: result: no
configure:2900: checking whether to build release libraries
configure:2912: result: yes
configure:3033: checking for C compiler version
configure:3042: cl --version >&5
./configure: line 3044: cl: command not found
configure:3053: $? = 127
configure:3042: cl -v >&5
./configure: line 3044: cl: command not found
configure:3053: $? = 127
configure:3042: cl -V >&5
./configure: line 3044: cl: command not found
configure:3053: $? = 127
configure:3042: cl -qversion >&5
./configure: line 3044: cl: command not found
configure:3053: $? = 127
configure:3073: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3095: cl -Gy -MD    conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 3097: cl: command not found
configure:3099: $? = 127
configure:3137: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "ICU"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "International Components for Unicode"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "73.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "ICU 73.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://icu-project.org/bugs"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://icu-project.org"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3142: error: in `/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Dev/ICU/icu/source':
configure:3144: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-cygwin
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=cl
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-Gy -MD '
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=cl
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value='-Gy -MD '
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_ICULEHB_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_ICULEHB_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_ICULEHB_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_ICULEHB_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-cygwin

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
AR=''
ARFLAGS=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='cygwin'
build_vendor='unknown'
build='x86_64-unknown-cygwin'
CC='cl'
CFLAGS='-Gy -MD '
COMPILE_LINK_ENVVAR=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
cross_buildroot=''
cross_compiling='no'
CXX='cl'
CXXFLAGS='-Gy -MD '
DATA_PACKAGING_MODE=''
DATA_TRUE=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
DEFS=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
DOXYGEN=''
dvidir='${docdir}'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_DEBUG='0'
ENABLE_RELEASE='1'
ENABLE_RPATH=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
ENABLE_STATIC=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
EXEEXT=''
EXTRAS_TRUE=''
FUZZER_TRUE=''
GENCCODE_ASSEMBLY=''
GREP=''
HAVE_MMAP=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='cygwin'
host_vendor='unknown'
host='x86_64-unknown-cygwin'
htmldir='${docdir}'
ICU_ECHO_C=''
ICU_ECHO_N='-n'
ICU_ECHO_T=''
ICUDATA_CHAR=''
ICUIO_TRUE=''
ICULEHB_CFLAGS=''
ICULEHB_LIBS=''
ICULIBSUFFIX=''
ICULIBSUFFIXCNAME=''
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_ICU_CONFIG='true'
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LAYOUTEX_TRUE=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIB_M=''
LIB_THREAD=''
LIB_VERSION_MAJOR='73'
LIB_VERSION='73.1'
LIBCFLAGS=''
LIBCXXFLAGS=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
LTLIBOBJS=''
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
OBJEXT=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://icu-project.org/bugs'
PACKAGE_NAME='ICU'
PACKAGE_STRING='ICU 73.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='International Components for Unicode'
PACKAGE_URL='http://icu-project.org'
PACKAGE_VERSION='73.1'
PACKAGE='icu'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
PKG_CONFIG=''
pkgicudatadir=''
platform_make_fragment_name=''
platform_make_fragment=''
platform=''
PLUGINS_TRUE=''
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
PYTHON=''
RANLIB=''
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
SAMPLES_TRUE=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
SED=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
TESTS_TRUE=''
thepkgicudatadir=''
TOOLS_TRUE=''
U_DEFAULT_SHOW_DRAFT=''
U_DISABLE_RENAMING=''
U_ENABLE_DYLOAD=''
U_ENABLE_TRACING=''
U_HAVE_DATA=''
U_HAVE_DIRENT_H=''
U_HAVE_EXTRAS=''
U_HAVE_FUZZER=''
U_HAVE_ICUIO=''
U_HAVE_INTTYPES_H=''
U_HAVE_LAYOUTEX=''
U_HAVE_LIB_SUFFIX=''
U_HAVE_NL_LANGINFO_CODESET=''
U_HAVE_PLACEMENT_NEW=''
U_HAVE_PLUGINS=''
U_HAVE_POPEN=''
U_HAVE_SAMPLES=''
U_HAVE_STRTOD_L=''
U_HAVE_TESTS=''
U_HAVE_TIMEZONE=''
U_HAVE_TOOLS=''
U_HAVE_TZNAME=''
U_HAVE_TZSET=''
U_HAVE_WCHAR_H=''
U_HAVE_WCSCPY=''
U_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=''
U_MAKE=''
U_NL_LANGINFO_CODESET=''
U_OVERRIDE_CXX_ALLOCATION=''
U_TIMEZONE=''
U_TZNAME=''
U_TZSET=''
UCLN_NO_AUTO_CLEANUP=''
UCONFIG_CFLAGS=''
UCONFIG_CPPFLAGS=''
UCONFIG_CXXFLAGS=''
UNICODE_VERSION='15.0'
VERSION='73.1'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "ICU"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "International Components for Unicode"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "73.1"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "ICU 73.1"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://icu-project.org/bugs"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://icu-project.org"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: ***See `config.log' for more details*** What does the config.log tell you?

Comment: Did you do this step: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat` The path will be different for VS2022: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsamd64_x86.bat"`

Comment: `./configure: line 3097: cl: command not found` looks to be the problem as it says the the msvc compiler can not be found.. I believe my second comment is very relevant. It does not seem like you executed the `vcvarsamd64_x86.bat` script that sets environment variables that will allow for the compiler to be found.

Comment: Since you are using powershell instead of cmd.exe this question may be the real problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124753/how-can-i-use-powershell-with-the-visual-studio-command-prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124753/how-can-i-use-powershell-with-the-visual-studio-command-prompt)

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you! It seems to have built and installed, though I don't know how to use the library in my VS project. `using icu::UnicodeString;` and the like does not work. Neither does `include <utypes.h>` and the like. I am still new so maybe I just don't understand how using libraries works. (I am used to python where installing is extremely simplified as you probably know.)

Comment: I expect its the same as any other library. Add entries for your `"C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories"` and add the required libraries in your `Linker->Input` also remember the msvc configurations (Release, Debug ...) are separate and usually there are different libraries for Debug and Release because these 2 configurations are incompatible with each other.

Comment: @drescherjm I have now done this (https://imgur.com/a/17QbxsV) though I still can't use the library.

Comment: It's very odd to have the same folder for the "Additional Include Directories" and "Additional Library Directories" I am not sure that is correct.

Comment: @drescherjm Okay, I just realised that vcpkg can do it for me, I probably misspelled it before. Also, the user guide does not mention it what so ever, so that isn't helpful. Anyway, that fixed it so that's fine.

Comment: Contrary to the posted answer, there is no reason to get Cygwin involved here – ICU has come with Windows [for a few years now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/international-components-for-unicode--icu-)... If you're using VS, on Windows, there's nothing to build or install; just include the header and add `icu.lib` to your linker inputs.

Answer (score -2):

ICU is already available as Cygwin package

See content of the last development packages
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libicu-devel/libicu-devel-72.1-1

There is no reason to mix `C++ Visual Studio 2022` with `Cygwin` and it is likely cumbersome (I do not use Visual Studio).

Cygwin has already all needed packages for development:

gcc-core
gcc-c++
make
cmake
..

and many mores. See full list at
https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html